# manage.py migrate failure on docker-compose file

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

i have issue, i have dockerfile with django configuration:

```
FROM python:3.11    
WORKDIR /app    
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=server.settings    
COPY requirements/prod.txt requirements/prod.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements/prod.txt
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000
# RUN python3 manage.py makemigrations
RUN python3 manage.py migrate
CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

and docker-compose for django and postgres:

```
services:
  django:
    image: auralab-django:latest
    container_name: auralab-django
    build:
      context: ./auralab
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./auralab:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://example_user:example_password@db:5432/auralab

  db:
    image: postgres:13
    container_name: auralab-db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: auralab
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

then i try `sudo docker-compose build`  without `makemigrations` and `migrate`, it build successfuly, but after there is no relations:

> relation "learning_student" does not exist
> LINE 1: ...t"."description", "learning_student"."image" FROM "learning_...

so for this i added makemigratons and migrate in my docker file but have an error during
`sudo docker-compose build` :

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
> return func(*args, **kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 275, in get_new_connection
> connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py", line 122, in connect
> conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known

here is my settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'example name',
    'USER': 'example user',
    'PASSWORD': 'example password',
    'HOST': 'db',
    'PORT': '5432',
  }
}
```

what can i do ?

Answer (score 2):

You do not have access to services declared in Compose file during building app image.
When you run:

```
RUN python3 manage.py migrate
```

It tries to apply migrations to database during building which it does not have connection. You can run migrations and other commands in entrypoints.

Comment: Alternatively, to run migrate only once when the container is up: `docker exec -it auralab-django python <path_to_project_dir>/manage.py migrate`